# drupal fivestar rating

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, rating, fivestar

I want some suggestion regarding the usage of fivestar rating module in drupal. The requirement is like this:

A customer can rate a manufacturer according to service, quality of work, overall score etc. But I am not sure as to how can I integrate this functionality using fivestar module? any ideas?!

## EDIT - 1

What I meant was that, can I achieve this functionality through drupals fivestar rating module?! or should I develop another module of my own?!

Comment: Provide some more information on what you have tried, any code help etc, if you need assistance installing the module. Chances are rtfm will do you some good here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "manufacturer" is a content type or a user a quick and simple way can be seen below:

1. Create a new content type called something like "review" or manufacturer review", etc
2. Add a node reference/user reference field to the content type (depending on the manufacturer's type) so that customers can link their review to a specific manufacturer
3. Add Fivestar Rating fields to the review content type for each of your criteria (service, quality, overall score, etc)

Now you a content type of reviews that you can use however you like (with Views module, etc).

**EDIT:** To use a node reference/user reference field, you will need to have the [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck) installed and enabled.  A good description/source of info on the node reference field can be found at http://pras.net.np/blogs/guide-cck-nodereference

You may also want to take a look at the [Node comments module](http://drupal.org/project/nodecomment) or the [Custom review module](http://drupal.org/project/custom_review) to integrate with [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) to create a custom review process.  For more information about creating a custom review process with these modules, see [Fivestar's Documentation.](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/fivestar)

Comment: Ok, i see a point in what you are saying. Could you explain me the 2nd point please!

Comment: @mad_programmer #2 in the list or my other suggestions?

Comment: and is there any way to insert a module in a page?! just curious to know about it.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include info on the reference fields. You need the CCK module installed and need to create a new content type for your reviews then add fields to it. As for your other question, I do not know what you mean, you should make another question instead of asking here.